# searching a value from a column of values in excel

Tags: excel

I have a column of numbers which are to be compared with another column of number if suppose an element in A2 matches with any of the element in column B it should display as paid or else not paid and the following element in A3 again have to be compared with column B element(first to last) this cycle continues untill all the elements in coulmn A are done. can you help me on this please

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. This forum is not for requesting others to do your work for you. If you have specific questions you are having issues with, show us what you have tried and then we can attempt to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNTIF(). The first argument is the range and the second is the item you're searching for. The result is the number of items found in the range (or zero if nothing is found)

Comment: But here I am searching one element from column of elements where i don't know that element exists or not? so I don't think count function works.thanks